# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'wordpress' when trying to create DB user

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-wordpress-with-amazon-rds/4/

On the above link, I have created a RDS and set it's security group to grant access to the EC2-instance. All using the same db name, default VPC, as in the tutorial.
RDS= MySql 5.7.33

Commands:

sudo yum install -y mysql
| 3.7 kB  00:00:00
Package 1:mariadb-5.5.68-1.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version

export MYSQL_HOST=dap.somehostname.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

mysql --user=admin --password=mypassword  wordpress

ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'wordpress'

I have read many related posts but none is specifically to connect RDS on AWS as in the tutorial or could indicate a solution. Youtube is also full of old videos all 3 that I tried failed.

Can someone point me to a solution please?

Comment: Did you follow the "Additional configuration" steps when creating the RDS instance to create the wordpress database?

Comment: yes, I did Aron, thanks for asking

Comment: Have you created initial database named "wordpress"? Also can you try like this `mysql -u admin -p $password -h dap.somehostname.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` ?

Comment: OMG I didn't name it wordpress... duh! Will try it now thanks!

Comment: I simply used the same command: mysql --user=<user> password=<password><my db name> and it works! Thanks for answering this simple stupid question, God bless!!